# former worked code does not work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-xe

There are code below and worked well before

```
unit Unit1;
  {$DEFINE _Full}
 // {$DEFINE _Trial}

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms;


{$ifdef  _Trial}

_programname='abc';


{$endif}

{$ifdef  _Full}

_programname='abc';


{$endif}
```

but today I run Delphi and try to compile, it reported

```
Identifier redeclared: '_programname'
```

it looks like

```
  {$DEFINE _Full}
```

does not work

your comment welcome

Comment: Don't you have `_Trial` defined in your project build configuration ? Anyway, why don't you use `{$ELSE}` ?

Comment: _Trial is not defined, _Full has been defined

Comment: Why did you use so many version tags? Do they mean anything?

Comment: @arachide, that's what I see. I've asked if you don't have it defined in the project build configuration (e.g. by mistake). But still, using `{$ELSE}` is the way to go here.

Comment: @arachide, [`CTRL + SHIFT + F11`](http://i.imgur.com/qzYuF2j.png) ?

Comment: TLama or David Heffernan are right, my code was written a long time ago( 5,6 years before), I have forgot some detail, please reply as answer I will accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both conditionals are defined. That can be inferred from the compiler error.

Either single line `//` comments do not comment out defines. Or you are defining `_Trial` at the project level. To the very best of my knowledge, a single line `//` comment will comment out a directive. So I presume that `_Trial` is defined at the project level.

The idiomatic way to comment out defines is like this:

```
{.$DEFINE _Trial}
```

For an either or condition it might be simpler with a single conditional:

```
{$IFDEF _Trial}
  .... stuff for trial version
{$ELSE}
  .... stuff for full version
{$END}
```

All that said, perhaps your actual problem is different because the code you show does not match the error message you reported. I'd expect an error saying that a keyword was expected, but identifier `_programname` found. The code in the question appears to omit the `const` keyword before the declaration of `_programname`.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting this under the assumption that _programname is supposed to be a constant, as that is most consistent with t
he code you are showing.  Your constant declarations need to be declared in a CONST section block.  Try this:

```
unit Unit1;
  {$DEFINE _Full}
 // {$DEFINE _Trial}

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms;

CONST  //<< Changed Code

{$ifdef  _Trial}

_programname='abc';

{$endif}

{$ifdef  _Full}

_programname='abc';


{$endif}
```

Comment: If the missing `const` keyword was the issue, the compilation would fail on *E2029 Declaration expected but identifier '_programname' found* error.

Comment: I have the code 'const', it is not the problem, all my code are for delphi7, they worked before, but today when I compile again, they reported error

Comment: I compiled this with XE2;  as you had posted the code, it would not compile per TLama's comment.  After including in a CONST block, it compiled fine.  The only way I was able to reproduce the error you posted was to declare a var _programname:string; This suggests you have another declaration for _programname somewhere in your project.  I did compile a test Delphi 7 program with a _programname variable declared in a separate unit and got no error, but I did with XE2 under the same conditions.